# Get argument from different method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, attributes, arguments

I am passing object as follows

```
test = TestClass(parameter1=''first_name', parameter2='last_name')
```

And in another method I am accessing parameter1 as

```
print test.parameter1
```

I get output as `first_name`

But if I have variable which contains value assigned to parameter1. Can I use variable to get value?

```
var = 'parameter1'
```

What's the right way to perform like `test.var`? For this I get `attribution error`.

What's the programming word for 'parameter1', is it options, argument options?

Comment: parameter1 is an 'attribute' of object test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you need getattr function:

```
getattr(test, var)
```